# Pdf reader component for windows universal apps

Tags: c#, xaml, pdf, win-universal-app

I am looking for PDF reader component for my Windows Phone App which is universal store app (will try to port to Windows Store app later). Haven't found anything except ComponentOne which works really bad on low-end devices and have memory leakage in general. 
What are your suggestions?

Comment: Your question is better suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com because the SO rules do not allow 3rd party library recommendations.

Comment: You can check the solution from this [article](http://blog.apitron.com/2014/12/convert-pdf-to-image-in-univeral-windows-store-app.html) about PDF rendering for Univeral Windows Store App.